# 301 http response without Location header

Tags: apache, http, web

If I create an application that sends a 301 response to the browser without sending a Location header how would the browser respond to the response.
When I tried a POC using nodejs looks like the browser is redirecting the request to /
Is it browser depended or a documented spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers should just render the HTML body. `Location` is optional.